# export 'default' (imported as 'LoadingButton') was not found in '@mui/lab/LoadingButton' (module has no exports)

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, npm-install

After `npm install @mui/lab, loading buttons from mui give this error.(module has no exports)

Answer (score 5):

Closing and Restarting the npm localhost server worked for me.
However you might have installed the package in the wrong directory.

Comment: Worked for me too in a similar situation. The directory structure of the client-side software had radically changed, and it was just too much for the localhost server to swallow.